# I am learning to use JNI, and there are garbled characters when I use ReleaseStringUTFChars

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I am learning the API usage of JNI under the manjaro system.
This is a Java native function declaration.

```java
/**
 * @author aszswaz
 * @date 2021/4/15 20:00:36
 */
public class HelloWorld {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("HelloWorld");
    }

    /**
     * 声明 native方法
     */
    public static native String sayHello(String name);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // 调用函数
        String text = sayHello("yangxin");
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

This is the generated JNI header file.

```c
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class HelloWorld */

#ifndef _Included_HelloWorld
#define _Included_HelloWorld
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     HelloWorld
 * Method:    sayHello
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_sayHello
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jstring);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

This is the C language code that implements native.

```c
//
// Created by aszswaz on 2021/4/15.
//

#include "HelloWorld.h"
#include "stdio.h"

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_sayHello(JNIEnv *env, jclass aClass, jstring j_str) {
    const char *c_str = NULL;
    char buff[128] = {0};
    // 开辟一块新的内存用于存储字符串，如果内存不够了，会获取失败
    c_str = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, j_str, NULL);
    printf("origin str: %s\n", c_str);
    if (c_str == NULL) {
        printf("out of memory.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    // 替换字符串
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, j_str, c_str);
    // 打印
    printf("Java Str:%s\n", c_str);
    sprintf(buff, "hello %s\n", c_str);
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, buff);
}
```

This is the compile and run instructions I executed.

```sh
$ javac HellWorld.java
$ javah -jni HelloWorld
$ gcc -I${JAVA_HOME}/include -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/linux -fPIC -shared HelloWorld.c HelloWorld.h -o libHelloWorld.so
$ java -Djava.library.path=. HelloWorld
```

This is the result of the operation.

```sh
origin str: yangxin
Java Str:%gz�
hello %gz±
```

Why does it look abnormal and how can I fix it?
I have tried to delete the ReleaseStringUTFChars function, and it can output normally. Why does it appear garbled when I add ReleaseStringUTFChars?

Comment: `ReleaseStringUTFChars` must be clearing the buffer which is generally not a good idea

Comment: Also, please change the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the JNI manual](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html)

> ReleaseStringUTFChars
>
> void ReleaseStringUTFChars(JNIEnv *env, jstring string, const char
> *utf);
>
> Informs the VM that the native code no longer needs access to utf. The
> utf argument is a pointer derived from string using
> GetStringUTFChars().

So obviously it's a bug to use `c_str` after telling the VM you don't need it any more. Just call `ReleaseStringUTFChars()` after building `buff`